# How does Resource bundle Hierarchy works with variant?

Tags: java, properties, locale, resourcebundle

When variant doesn't exists, how to be redirected to "middle default".

With the following resources:

```
> Labellisation_fr
> Labellisation_fr_NBA
> Labellisation_fr_NBA_SPURS
> Labellisation_fr_NBA_BULLS
> Labellisation_en
> Labellisation_en_NBA
> Labellisation_en_NBA_SPURS
> Labellisation_en_NBA_BULLS
```

Current result for: **Labellisation_fr_NBA_LAKERS** > **Labellisation_fr**

Expected result for: **Labellisation_fr_NBA_LAKERS** > **Labellisation_fr_NBA**

Do you know how to achieve this?

And my code so far

```
    String variant = league + "_" + team
    ServiceResourceBundle serviceResourceBundle = new ServiceResourceBundle(BUNDLE_BASE_NAME)
    Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage(serviceResourceBundle.getLocale().getLanguage()).setVariant(variant).build()
    serviceResourceBundle.setLocale(locale)
```

Comment: A locale is language fr + country FR (9917?) + variant (1111?)..

Comment: @JoopEggen  I would like to configure messages based on a "functional" variant, that is not really "language" related

Comment: I almost guessed that, but then language=fr, country=NBA, variant=LAKERS. At least that is customary for the underscore usage. Do `new Locale("fr", "NBA", "LAKERS")`